# Get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when trying to @Autowire repository on controller Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, javabeans

Im new in Spring Boot. I have to connect my app to MySQL servver. At thetime of creating back side of app, I got a problem with beans in Spring. When I try to run this in my server I get the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.bagyt.reposotories.UniversityRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as an autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This is my controller class

```
package com.bagyt.controller;
import com.bagyt.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.bagyt.model.University;
import com.bagyt.repositories.UniversityRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/universityApi")
public class UniversityController {

    @Autowired
    UniversityRepository universityRepository;

    @GetMapping("/university")
    public List<University> getAllNotes() {
        return universityRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/university")
    public University createNote(@Valid @RequestBody University note) {
        return universityRepository.save(note);
    }

    @GetMapping("/university/{id}")
    public University getNoteById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long universityId) {
        return universityRepository.findById(universityId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("University", "id", universityId));
    }

    @PutMapping("/university/{id}")
    public University updateNote(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long universityId,
                           @Valid @RequestBody University universityDetails) {

        University university = universityRepository.findById(universityId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("University", "id", universityId));

        university.setName(universityDetails.getName());
        university.setEmail(universityDetails.getEmail());
        university.setDescription(universityDetails.getDescription());
        university.setPhotoLink(university.getPhotoLink());

        University updatedNote = universityRepository.save(university);
        return updatedNote;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/university/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteNote(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long universityId) {
        University note = universityRepository.findById(universityId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("University", "id", universityId));

        universityRepository.delete(note);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}`
```

My repository

```
package com.bagyt.repositories;

import com.bagyt.model.University;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    @Repository
    public interface UniversityRepository extends JpaRepository<University, Long> {


    }
```

I have tested and made sure the error is in my @Autowired line in the controller. 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where do you have class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`? I mean package.

Comment: at the Main class of app

Comment: and the package...

Comment: src/main/java/com.bagyt(name of project)/controller/BagytApplication

Comment: Can you paste that class in your question?

Comment: https://github.com/balamanova/BagytWebSite This is on github. oK i will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) says about `@SpringBootApplication`

> @ComponentScan: enable @Component scan on the package where the application is located

That means Spring will look for beans in your `com.bagyt.controller`, that is the same package where a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` has been defined and its subpackages.

You should move `BagytApplication` in `com.bagyt` package if you want to scan for components in other packages such as `com.bagyt.repository`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller package is either same package or sub package of class with @springBootApplication. If any dependency(@controller,@Service,@Repository) is in different package structure use @componentscan(give package name ).I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

On springboot main class, you can add

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.bagyt.repositories")
```